# Python: Bulk insert data into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, bulkinsert

I want to quickly put data into a sql server database. Is there a possibility to access the bulk copy functionality of [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from CPython? I know it would be possible from IronPython and I also know that I could create text files which I could load via T-SQL. But I would prefer a solution where I can pass in data directly from CPython.

Answer (score 0):

The flat file solution would be the simplest solution, but if you really need an alternative then you might be able to use `ctypes` to drive the SQL Server ODBC [bulk copy extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130792.aspx).